# How to call AAD graph from Ibiza extension

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to call AAD Graph, but I'm getting an error.
Here is how I'm trying to make a call:

```
MsPortalFx.Base.Net.ajax({
        uri: `https://graph.windows.net/<id>/servicePrincipals/<id>?api-version=1.6-internal`,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        setAuthorizationHeader: true,
    })
```

I can see that Bearer token is supplied in the Authorization header, but here is the error I'm getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: <name>
request-id: <request-id>
client-request-id: <client-request-id>
x-ms-dirapi-data-contract-version: 1.6-internal
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Duration: 519919
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2020 22:49:42 GMT
Content-Length: 212

{"odata.error":{"code":"Authentication_MissingOrMalformed","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Access Token missing or malformed."},"requestId":"<id>","date":"2020-11-23T22:49:42"}}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Comment: Please check your access token at https://jwt.io/. The [`aud`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) should be `https://graph.windows.net`.

Comment: The error information Authentication_MissingOrMalformed it means that the access resource does not match the AUD of access token.you need to change the resource to https://graph.windows.net during get the access token. and also  please share correlation id and time stamp of error message

Comment: Got it. Trying this change.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sruthi said, the error information Authentication_MissingOrMalformed it means that the access resource does not match the AUD of access token.

You need to get the access token following this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Your-Tenant-ID>/oauth2/token

// request body:
grant_type=client_credentials
client_id=<Your Portal Application ID>
client_secret=<Your client secret>
resource=https://graph.windows.net    // used to call AAD Graph API
```

[image]

[image]

**Or** with the `v2.0` endpoint:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Your-Tenant-ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

// request body:
grant_type=client_credentials
client_id=<Your Portal Application ID>
client_secret=<Your client secret>
scope=https://graph.windows.net/.default    // used to call AAD Graph API
```